# bootstrap affix how to fix it to a parent element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap affix in a similar way to "How to Format" on the right side of **Ask Question** page of stackoverflow.

I can make it affix to the viewport by adding a css `.affix { top: 70px }` and use `class='affix' data-spy='affix'` in html, but what if I want the affix element to be fixed to a parent element?

For example, if I have such html:

```
<div class='affix-container'>
  <div class='left-panel'>
    some form, including a textarea
  </div>
  <div class='right-panel affix' data-spy='affix'>
    how to format
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like `right-panel` to be affixed only relative to `affix-container`, so when I scroll down, if `affix-container` is still in viewport, then affix `right-panel`, otherwise let `right-panel` scroll up.

Can I still do this if affix-container is resizable? ie. its size/height increases with the resize of textarea it contains?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the left-panel's scroll movement, you need to use a scroll-spy with the affix. You'll need the body tag setup first.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="200">
```

Here the offset will ensure that tracking only starts at 200 from the top depending on header size etc. The right-panel then gets id="myScrollspy" e.g.

```
<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-2" id="myScrollspy">
    <div class="right-panel affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="400">
    </div>
</div>
```

The fixing of the element is fixed at 400 offset (useful if you have a header etc.). You can then change the position with css as you scroll from a certain point forward. I've added things that's from my code extract and can be used/ignored i.e. on xs screens I hide my scrollspy, otherwise it takes up 2 cols in the parent row.

```
.affix {
   top: 100px;
 }
```

Should work with resizable container, but I didn't test it.